# Merging millions of data using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

i need help/tips

i have a huge amount of json data that needs to be merged, sorted and filtered. right now, they're separated into different folders.  almost 2GB of json files.

what i'm doing right now is:

- reading all files inside each folders
- appending JSON parsed data to an `Array variable` inside my script.
- sorting the `Array variable`
- filtering.
- save it to one file

i'm rethinking that instead of `appending parsed data to a variable`, maybe i should store it inside a file ?.. what do you guys think ?
what approach is better when dealing with this kind of situation ?

By the way, i'm experiencing a 
[`Javascript Heap out of memory`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJZos.png)

Comment: A such amount of data, doesn't have to be loaded in the memory at the same time.

Comment: so you think storing parsed data into file instead of storing it to a variable is better?

Comment: I would filter first, then sort.

Answer (score 0):

you could use some kind of database, e.g. MySQL with table's engine "memory" so it would be saved in ram only and would be blazing quick and would be erased after reboot but you should truncate it anyways after the operation while it's all temp. When you will have data in the table, it will be easy to filter/sort required bits and grab data incrementally by let's say 1000 rows and parse it as needed. You will not have to hold 2gigs of data inside js.

2gigs of data will probably block your js thread during loops and you will get frozen app anyways.

If you will use some file to save temporary data to avoid database, i recommend using some temporary disk which would be mounted on RAM, so you will have much better i/o speed.

Comment: thanks, but to be honest, i'm not sure why would i use db? it's just files that needs to be merged, filtered, and sorted before storing to an actual database. that's why i used nodejs.

Comment: if you don't see any need to use database and want to store temp data on file while sorting/filtering etc. Just use ram disk and it will be quick. Nodejs is just js runner and js is single threaded and it becomes frozen if you have some cpu intensive tasks running. That's why i would use some db solution to manipulate larger data set. Of course, you can use other threads with workers, but it might become overengineered.